# While registering the sever on xmpp jabberid is coming invalid, while on creation it has been successfully validated

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I am creating a iphone[image] chatting application using XMPP.For that I have created jabber id using  https://jabb.im/reg/  and it has been validated.

But when i am registering my server on the https://list.jabber.at then it is  showing invalid jabbid.

[image]

kindly help me with XMPP and Jabberid.
suggest if have something better options for making an iphone app with xmpp.

Comment: You can follow one of the tutorial from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44885086/1031944